# Error with Google Maps Flutter in Android Studio

Tags: android, gradle, flutter

I try to add google maps on flutter, I added the following dependence:

```
dependencies:
 google_maps_flutter: ^0.5.17
```

and its respective api key in android and ios.

But when running the project it marks the following:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:preDebugBuild'.
> Android dependency 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks' has different version for the compile (15.0.1) and runtime (16.0.1) classpath. You should manually set the same version via DependencyResolution

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4s
Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

and try to add the dependencies manually in buil.gradle

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
    }
```

and this in build.gradle in project level

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

but still with the same.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to migrate your project to AndroidX. I had a similar issue in my project.

Open you Android folder in Android studio, go to `File -> Sync Project With Gradle Files` and then `Refactor -> Migrate to AndroidX`